# How to get the first record from a group of records MS sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have several business Unit ids with dates that records were added and I want to get the rows of when the last record was added only

```
2018-06-26 22:54:51.190 1
2018-07-05 10:36:49.563 1
2018-07-16 10:14:04.093 1
2018-07-17 15:24:22.173 1
2018-07-19 10:40:24.700 1
2018-07-23 09:53:34.607 13
2018-07-23 09:53:57.107 13
2018-09-04 14:55:04.860 4
2018-09-04 14:56:34.147 4
```

should be

```
2018-07-19 10:40:24.700 1
2018-07-23 09:53:57.107 13
2018-09-04 14:56:34.147 4
```

I tried this

```
select  
mnt.DateAdded,
bu.BuId
from BusinessUnit bu
inner join MagicNumbersTable mnt on mnt.BuId = bu.BuId
where bu.BuId in  (select top 1 b.BuId
                     from BusinessUnit b inner join MagicNumbersTable m on b.BuId = m.BuId
                     group by  b.BuId, m.DateAdded
                     order by m.DateAdded desc)
```

which only return one record and not each first record order  by dateadded desc per bu

What would the correct way be of achieving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` function with *ties* clause :

```
select top (1) with ties mnt.DateAdded, bu.BuId
from BusinessUnit bu inner join 
     MagicNumbersTable mnt 
     on mnt.BuId = bu.BuId
order by row_number() over (partition by bu.BuId order by mnt.DateAdded desc);
```

However, you can simply use `GROUP BY` clasue with `MAX()`, but assuming you want some more info with this. If not, then `GROUP BY`clause is enough to implement not need to use `subuqery` or `row_number()`

Comment: With an admittedly trivial example, I seem to be getting a "better" / "cheaper" / "shorter" execution plan with the "traditional" `WHERE row_number_from_sub_query = 1`?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/723ef/1  Do you have any rigorous links *(as in, more rigorous than my nonsense)* that would suggest using `WITH TIES` and `ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER()` can perform better?

Comment: Great, thanks. Now I have learned something new. There are multiple columns to reference which is why the simple group by wouldn't work

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, I wrote this. What you think about this.

```
create table #maxDate (date datetime, id int)

insert #maxDate values
  ( '2018-06-26 22:54:51.190', 1)
, ( '2018-07-05 10:36:49.563', 1)
, ( '2018-07-16 10:14:04.093', 1)
, ( '2018-07-17 15:24:22.173', 1)
, ( '2018-07-19 10:40:24.700', 1)
, ( '2018-07-23 09:53:34.607', 13)
, ( '2018-07-23 09:53:57.107', 13)
, ( '2018-09-04 14:55:04.860', 4)
, ( '2018-09-04 14:56:34.147', 4)

select id, max(date) date from #maxDate
group by id

id              date
-------------------------------
 1      2018-07-19 10:40:24.700
 4      2018-09-04 14:56:34.147
 13     2018-07-23 09:53:57.107
```

Revert me, if query needs updates.